# Проблема печати QR-кодов на QR принтере

Tags: c#

В чем у меня проблема? Я не знаю как для лейбла (сам QR-код который
клеться на товара) выделить область (высота,ширина), а на основе этой области печатались QR-коды из картинки.

Что происходит сейчас чтобы найти **Size** и **Point** было потрачено много лайблов.

**Код**

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PrintDocument pd = new PrintDocument();
            pd.PrintPage += PrintPage;
            pd.Print();
        }

        private void PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
            Image img = Image.FromFile("rezult.png");

            //One
            System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(270, 250);
            System.Drawing.Point location = new System.Drawing.Point(70, 170);
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(location, size);
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, rectangle);
          
        }
```

**Результат**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все хорошо,но для 4 в 1 qr уже плохо их сканировать не реально(уже не подходит Size и Point).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 System.Drawing.Size size = new System.Drawing.Size(220, 190);
 System.Drawing.Point location = new System.Drawing.Point(90, 200);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам помогло изменение размера и положения?

Comment: На скрин гляньте.